# Better way to iterate over strongly typed rows from DataView?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Using dotnet 2.0.
I currently have code like this :

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dsTrans.Transactions, filterSpec, sortSpec, 
                           DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

foreach (DataRowView dvr in dv)
{
    DSTransactions.TransactionsRow transRow = (DSTransactions.TransactionsRow)dvr.Row;
    // do something with transRow
}
```

where "dsTrans" is a strongly typed DataSet. I'm wondering if there is a more type-safe way to iterate over the rows of the DataView, which does not involve using a cast (or using the "as" keyword).

(Note that some ordering and filtering is needed, which is why a DataView is used)

Thanks.

Comment: Might want to rename the title from interate to iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
// Only one cast here
Enumerator<DSTransactions.TransactionsRow> enumer = (IEnumerator<DSTransactions.TransactionsRow>)dv.GetEnumerator();
while (enumer.MoveNext())
{
    // enumer.Current will be of type DSTransactions.TransactionsRow
    Console.WriteLine(enumer.Current);
}
enumer.Dispose();
```